# Is the leading term of a polynomial the product of the leading terms of the factors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I dont understand the last sentence of this:

[image]

Why is the leading term of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ the product of the leading terms of $q(x)$, $x-a_1$ and $x-a_2$?

Is it true that in general, for any polynomial $f(x)$, the leading term is the product of the leading terms of its factors?

Its from a paper about factoring polynomials: [https://www.math.utah.edu/~wortman/1050-text-fp.pdf](https://www.math.utah.edu/%7Ewortman/1050-text-fp.pdf)

Comment: What is the product $(a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n)\times(b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_mx^m)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i dont know, a polynomial?

Comment: Yes, but which one?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos its the product of two polynomials, i dont understand what you are trying to say

Comment: I am asking you which polynomial do you get wen you multiply $a_0+a_1+\cdots+a_nx^n$ and $b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_mx^m$. For instance, what is its constant term? And what is its leading term?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos constant term is $a_0b_0$ and leading term is $a_nx^nb_mx^m$

Comment: Why don't you simply say that the leading term is $a_nb_mx^{n+m}$?

Comment: Anyway, in the case you missed, you have asserted yourself that the leading term of the product is the product of the leading terms.